# MapBox Android how to hide mapbox label

Tags: android, mapbox

[image: Screenshot]

How to hide mapbox info label at bottom left corner?

Comment: you need to purchase that library

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The marked answer is wrong, incanus was referring to the older, now deprecated, SDK. Attribution is required because:

- Mapbox’s map designs are copyrighted
- The OpenStreetMap data source’s ODbL license requires attribution
- Other data sources used in our satellite, streets, and terrain maps also require attribution

If your map does not use any of these data sources, and does not use Mapbox’s designs, like Streets, Light, or Outdoors, then you are not required to provide attribution.

In Android you can move the attribution to another position if you need to using the correct attribute in the mapview XML. If your map doesn't fit any of the cases listed above, removing the attribution can be done in XML like so:

```
mapbox:attribution_enabled="false"
```

When it comes to hiding the Mapbox logo, All non-Enterprise accounts are required to display the Mapbox logo when using any Mapbox maps. Therefore, you can't remove it.

Sources: https://www.mapbox.com/help/attribution/, 
https://www.mapbox.com/help/mapbox-logo/

Comment: I am using a map for seafarer and MapView has a `@string/style_mapbox_streets`. Is that what you mean by `satellite`, `streets`? Does that mean it refers to the styling used in the map? DSo I need the attribution? In our app, we only use the map ala carte from the tutorial. We don't really do much.

Comment: This gives me a compiler error: "error: attribute attribution_enabled not found.
error: failed linking file resources."

Answer (score 16):

Just disable the attribution and logo, as follows:

```
mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setAttributionEnabled(false);
mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setLogoEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 11):

The approved answer doesn't work anymore as of Mapbox 10.0.

In the newest mapbox you can change logo and attributions visibility like this, from code:

```kotlin
mapView.logo.updateSettings {
    enabled = false
}

mapView.attribution.updateSettings {
    enabled = false
}
```

From XML:

```xml
app:mapbox_logoEnabled="false"
app:mapbox_attributionEnabled="false"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this,please:

```
 mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(36,50))
                            .zoom(10)
                            .tilt(45.0)
                            .build()),
                    10000);

            mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setAttributionEnabled(false);
            mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setLogoEnabled(false);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

To hide Mapbox attribution and logo, we can access corresponding views by reflection then change their visibility using below method:

```
private void hideAttributionsView(){
    UiSettings uiSettings = mMapBoxMap.getUiSettings();
    try {
        Field attributionsViewField = UiSettings.class.getDeclaredField("attributionsView");
        attributionsViewField.setAccessible(true);
        Field logoViewField = UiSettings.class.getDeclaredField("logoView");
        logoViewField.setAccessible(true);

        View attributionsView = (View) attributionsViewField.get(uiSettings);
        View logoView = (View) logoViewField.get(uiSettings);

        attributionsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        logoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```